# "Unknown network error" Instagram + Proxydroid on Genymotion Android emulator

Tags: android, proxy, instagram, emulation, genymotion

I am using Genymotion Android emulator(Samsung Galaxy S2, 4.1.1 API 16) and have installed Genymotion ARM tanslation. After that I downloaded the Instagram APK and it works very well.

However I wan't to use it with Proxydroid. When I enter the proxysettings and try  whatsmyip in the browser it shows the proxy. So everything is good. But as soon as I activate proxydroid I get "Unknown network error" when I try to login to Instagram.

Has anyone had any similar issue and knows a solution?